# Mongoose Query with where

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongoose query which finds all the rewards which a user got and not yet redeemed.

```
Reward.find({user: user, redeemed: false}).exec(callback)
```

I want to change it to all the rewards which are not redeemed, and the rewards which are redeemed today.
Is this the right way to go.

```
Reward.find({user:user})
      .where('redeemed').equals('false')
      .where('redeemed').equals('true').gt(yesterday)
      .exec(callback)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `or` query

```
Reward.find({
  user:user
  $or:[{
        redeemed: false
    },
    {
        redeemed: true
        redeemed_date: {
            $gt : yesterday
        }
    }]
  }, callback)
```

For a better readability you can use `or` as a promise

```
    Reward.find({user:user})
      .or([{redeemed: false},
        {
            redeemed: true,
            redeemed_date: {
                $gt : yesterday
            }
        }])
      .exec(callback)
```